# Can I create a second instance of a singleton in a DLL?

Tags: c++, dll, singleton, static-libraries

I have a static library which contains singletons. I need to load a separate instance of those singletons in the same process for testing purposes.

So I have created a DLL which links the same static library, and then the main process loads that DLL.

As soon as the DLL tries to load, I get access violations when trying to access the static instance pointers in the singletons.

Some posts that I have read say that it's impossible and that I need a second process, while others say that each DLL gets it's own copies of all the static variables in the static library it links, which suggests that this should work..

Is what I am trying to do possible?

Comment: Can you show the relevant code that is giving access violations?  How soon do you mean when you say "as soon as the DLL tries to load"?

Comment: Mark was right, see comments below his post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the time a singleton is really meant to be only one - your request is unusual.

I know that linking a static library into a DLL can result in multiple instances of static variables, because I've seen it myself. Each DLL or EXE gets its own copy of the static library via the linker, and thus its own copy of the static variables.

The access violations may come from problems with initialization order. The best way to control that is to make sure the static variables are within a function that initializes them just-in-time, rather than global variables.

Comment: Or the libs are allocating/using named system resources (such as mutexes, events, etc) and are quite-rightly stomping on each other in the process. This is extremely common when 'involved' static-libs find themselves in duplicity in a single process address space.

Comment: @Mark: You were right about the initialization order issue. I changed to DLL to instantiate the singleton on request instead, and I'm not getting the access violations anymore, but now both instance pointers end up pointing at the same object. I don't understand why they don't each get their own copy.

Comment: Actually, I got it. After retrieving the singleton from the DLL, calling GetInstance() on that singleton inside one of the translation units of the main process yields the instance pointer of the singleton from the main process. But, when I export a function from the DLL that calls GetInstance() inside one of the DLL's translation units, I do get a unique pointer. Thanks for the help =)